# Restrict access to specific users

Tags: content-restriction, user-access

Is there a built-in function that would allow me to restrict access to registered users until the official launch date in Wordpress 3.4.2? The blog is self-hosted.

Comment: Restrict access to registered users to the entire site, or just the WordPress Dashboard back-end?  Do you want to restrict access to everyone?

Comment: Yes I want the entire blog to be accessible only to registered users so the content manager can update it while I finish styling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Place it in your theme's `functions.php` or a plugin.

```
function tst($a) {
  if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
    wp_die('You are not allowed to view this page');
  }
}
add_filter('template_redirect','tst');
```

You can still get to the login page like normal by going to "/wp-login.php" or "/wp-admin".

Alternately, you could use [`wp_safe_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) or [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) instead of [`wp_die`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) to send people to a "Coming soon" page or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous plugins that do this already. Search Google for:

```
wordpress restrict site access
```